# How can I make javax validation both of sub class and super class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring framework,
and I faced the inheritance problem when I write Controller logic.

First of all,
this is my Controller code snippet

```
@PostMapping("/pay/detail")
public ResponseEntity<PayDetail.Response> getPayDetail(
    @Valid PayDetail.Request payDetail
) {

    ... some code
}
```

and PayDetail class looks like this

```
public class PayDetail {    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class Request extends CommReqForm {
        @NotNull(message = "Not null please")
        private String work_type;
    }
}
```

and CommReqForm

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CommReqForm {

    @NotEmpty(message = "servicecode not empty")
    private String servicecode;

    @NotEmpty(message = "reqtype not empty")
    private String reqtype; 
}
```

I wish that I can validate both of PayDetail.Request and CommReqForm classes but It makes validation just only PayDetail.Request class.
How can I solve this problem?

@Valid cannot validate super class. I want to make both of sub class and super class validation.

Comment: Validation should also work for the super class. One thing to take into consideration is that `null` is allowed by `@NotEmpty`. So if you want to stop `null` from being assigned you need an additional `@NotNull` on it.

Comment: You said Validation show also work for the super class but In that case it wouldn't validate super class validation...

Comment: It should. It doesn't matter where the annotations are. As stated I suspect the error lies in your expectations (i.e not sending anything leading to `null` which is perfectly fine by `@NotEmpty` as it allows `null` values).